# Styled Components use calc function

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I feel like this shouldn't be too hard but I can't seem to figure it out after quite a bit of googling.  I'm using styled components in React and trying to set the width of an item based on a calc function with another scss variable.  Something like the width property shown here (this doesn't work):

```
const IconWrapper=styled.div`
  width: calc(50px - var(_someWidthVariable));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

The variable (`_someWidthVariable`) is generally set in rem units so something like `1rem`.

Is this possible?  How do you do this?  Also I've used styled components a bit now but not a ton and mostly just for direct setting values so I may be missing something obvious.